# Propagate keys with spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Before upgrading to spring boot 3, I could propagate keys to other microservices with just the following property:

spring.sleuth.propagation-keys=my_key

Now, after upgrading to spring boot 3, the spring-boot-starter-sleuth is not available anymore.

Can anyone please tell me how would I propagate keys between microservices with spring boot 3?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys` in Spring Boot 3. However, there is an alternative

Assuming that you are using Spring boot version `3.2.1` with dependency `io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave`, Adding custom baggage to Brave in Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer involves a few steps:

1. **Define the Custom Baggage Field**

   Choose a relevant name for your custom baggage field. This name will be used to identify and access the baggage value later.
2. **Configure Propagation (Optional)**

   By default, Micrometer-Brave automatically propagates context using B3 headers like `X-B3-TraceId` and `X-B3-SpanId`. If you want your custom baggage to be propagated similarly, consider setting the following property

   ```
    management.metrics.export.trace.propagation.type=B3
   ```
3. **Create a Bean for Baggage Field Injection**

   Implement a Spring bean of type `SingleBaggageField`. This bean configures the name and optional propagation format for your custom baggage field. Here's an example:

   ```java
    @Configuration
    public class CustomBaggageConfig {

       @Bean
       public SingleBaggageField customBaggageField() {
           return SingleBaggageField.create("my-custom-field")             
            .withPropagationFormat(BaggagePropagationFormat.W3C_TRACE_CONTEXT);
       }
    }
   ```
4. **Access and Manipulate Baggage**

   Use the Tracer bean, injected into your class or method, to interact with
   the baggage.

   To set the value:

   ```java
    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    // ...

    tracer.baggage().put("my-custom-field", "some-value");
   ```

   To get the value

   ```java
    String customValue = tracer.baggage().get("my-custom-field");
   ```
5. **Propagate Baggage (Optional)**

If you choose not to use B3 propagation for your custom baggage field, you'll need to manually inject it into outgoing requests or messages. This might involve adding custom headers or other context propagation mechanisms specific to your messaging system.

**Additional Tips:**

- Consider using the @Observed annotation on your methods to automatically start a span and inject the Tracer for easier baggage access.
- You can customize the propagation format for individual baggage fields using the withPropagationFormat method in the SingleBaggageField builder.
- Refer to the Micrometer-Brave documentation for more advanced configurations and details about baggage propagation

The following article might also be helpful:
https://amithkumarg.medium.com/distributed-tracing-for-spring-boot-3x-app-using-micrometer-brave-and-zipkin-a43fc107bff4